# Ignore certain words when reading a file

Tags: java, readfile

My program reads a text file and lists the frequencies of each word in the file. What I need to do next, is ignore certain words such as 'the','an' when reading the file. I have a created a list of these words but not sure how to implement it in the while loop. Thanks.

```
public static String [] ConnectingWords = {"and", "it", "you"};

public static void readWordFile(LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> wordcount) {
    // FileReader fileReader = null;
    Scanner wordFile;
    String word; // A word read from the file
    Integer count; // The number of occurrences of the word

    // LinkedHashMap <String, Integer> wordcount = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> ();

    try {
        wordFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("/Applications/text.txt"));
        wordFile.useDelimiter(" ");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
    while (wordFile.hasNext()) {
        word = wordFile.next();
        word = word.toLowerCase();

        if (word.contains("the")) {
            count = getCount(word, wordcount) + 0;
            wordcount.put(word, count);

        }
        // Get the current count of this word, add one, and then store the
        // new count:
        count = getCount(word, wordcount) + 1;
        wordcount.put(word, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's inside `getCount()` method? It's just `wordcount.get(word)`? Which version of Java are you using? Also consider closing the `Scanner`, otherwise you would have a resource leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one list which will have list of word need to ignore as:

```
List<String> ignoreAll= Arrays.asList("and","it", "you");
```

then in while loop add one condition that will ignore the word contains these words as

```
if(ignoreAll.contains(word)){
                 continue;

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code.

```
   public static HashSet<String> connectingWords;
    public static Map<String,Integer> frequencyMap;

    static  {
        connectingWords = new HashSet<>();
        connectingWords.add("and");
        connectingWords.add("it");
        connectingWords.add("you");
        frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/files/temp2.txt"));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] words = line.split("-");
                for (String word : words) {
                    if(connectingWords.contains(word)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Integer value = frequencyMap.get(word);
                    if(value != null) {
                        frequencyMap.put(word,value+1);
                    } else {
                        frequencyMap.put(word,0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        System.out.println(frequencyMap.values());

    }
```

It is better to store connecting words in a `HashSet` as it will provide quick access every time you invoke `contains` for every word in file. Also the word and its frequency can be maintained in a `Map`. Also I am assuming that delimiter for words is `-` and if it is something else you can modify the code. Also if you have any special requirement related to `case` you can change the code. I have tried it with file having `What-the-hell-is-going-on-and-it-is-good` input and it works fine.

Comment: IMO if we close `BufferedReader` it will take care of  closing of `FileReader` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have list words of exclusion list. Before updating the count, check the exclusion list.

```
public static void readWordFile (LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> wordcount) {

    List<String> excludeList = new ArrayList<>();
    excludeList.add("the"); // and so on
    //  FileReader fileReader = null;
    Scanner wordFile;
    String word;     // A word read from the file
    Integer count;   // The number of occurrences of the word

    //  LinkedHashMap <String, Integer> wordcount = new LinkedHashMap <String, Integer> ();

    try
    {
        wordFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("/Applications/text.txt"));
        wordFile.useDelimiter(" ");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
    while (wordFile.hasNext())
    {
        word = wordFile.next( );
        word = word.toLowerCase();

        if(!excludeList.contains(word)) {

        count = wordcount.get(word) + 1;
        wordcount.put(word, count);
        }

    }
```